# How can I read the DOCTYPE SYSTEM identifier with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, doctype, msxml

For a document which has a DOCTPYE declaration like

```
<!DOCTYPE RootElement SYSTEM "file.dtd">
```

Delphi 2009, using MSXML, reports that the systemId is empty (""):

```
Assert(Doc.DOMDocument.doctype.systemId <> ''); // fails!
```

while

```
Assert(Doc.DOMDocument.doctype.name = 'RootElement'); // ok
```

correctly verifies that the DOCTYPE name id "RootElement".

Is this a bug in Delphi (or my code) or am I using a version of MSXML which does not support this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSXML's DocumentType implementation is completely missing the DocumentType properties `publicId`, `systemId` and `internalSubset`. [MSDN api ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762645%28v=VS.85%29.aspx); the missing properties are specifically called out in [MS-DOM2CX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff460276%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

If you need this information you might have to try a different DOM implementation. Here's [one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/idom2-pas/). If you can use .NET classes, [System.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocumenttype.systemid%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) supports it too.

Answer (score 0):

In case [ProhibitDTD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762632%28VS.85%29.aspx) property is True try setting it to False.

Here's an [article](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2010/qt/delphi-txmldocument-dtd-is-prohibited.htm) with more details.